# How can I get the map of USA by get_stamenmap in r?

Tags: r, ggmap

I can't have google map, so I tried to use Stamen Maps

I tried:

```
library("ggmap")
us = get_stamenmap(place="USA")
ggmap(us)
```

But regardless of the place it always shows the following map:

[image]

While I need to have this map:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library("ggmap")

# lng/lat bounds of contiguous USA
bbox <- c(left = -125, bottom = 25, right = -65, top = 50)

us <- get_stamenmap(bbox = bbox, zoom = 5)
ggmap(us)
```